# Different results in IronOcr reading full image or partial contentArea

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm using IronOcr/Tesseract to extract text from an image.
I want to know the location of a pre-known piece of text and using this found rectangle to extract text from other images.

To verify the method, i used the same image twice, so i should get back the same piece of text i was looking for earlier.

However, when i use this rectangle to narrow down the 2nd search, i get no results.
Since no configuration, scaling, or resolution is changed between these two operations, i'm wondering why this is. **What am i doing wrong here?**

```
        var _recognizerIron = new IronTesseract();           
        const string file = "assets/sample.jpg";
        using var input = new OcrInput(file);
        var result = _recognizerIron.Read(input);
        
        var foundWord = result.Words.First(w => w.Text=="7210");
        // foundWord.Location: {X = 511 Y = 793 Width = 67 Height = 22}

        using var input2 = new OcrInput();
        input2.AddImage(file, new CropRectangle(foundWord.Location));
        var result2 = _recognizerIron.Read(input2);
        
        Console.Write(result2.Text);
        //Expected Result: result2.Text=="7210"
        //Actual Result: result2.Text==""
```

Comment: You are reading form a different file.  First is using input1 and second is using input2.  You should close the first file before read the second or set position of file to zero to read the same file twice.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your input, but it is the exact same file. Also it doesn't matter if the input1 is closed before using input2. When i enlarge the rectangle, it gives a result, so there's no issue with a file being in use whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

IronOCR may automatically upscale images to improve read accuracy.

To disable this behavior, set `TargetDPI = null` on OcrInput

```
using IronOcr;
var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
using (var Input = new OcrInput())
{
    Input.TargetDPI = null; //disable upscaling
    Input.AddImage("example.png");
    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
    Console.WriteLine(Result.Text);
}
```

Trouble-shooting articles on IronOcr:

[X and Y coordinates change in OcrResult Class](https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/85-x-and-y-coordinates-change)

[Examples of how to use TargetDPI](https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/108-reduce-file-size-of-output-pdf-in-ironocr)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. The TargetDPI is null by default anyway, but even setting it upfront doesn't make a difference. Even though i would expect the same upscaling is used for the same image. I'm just using a croprectangle in the second run. I would expect just a subset of the first result, with exact same coordinates.